# Old man got Still Fresh here?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash-2018

per le descriptione of *Still Fresh*:

> be a user on the site for less than 6 months before Winter Bash, or join during Winter Bash; have earned at least 25 reputation

I joined Meta in February 2017 and has more than 7.5k reputation, and I still got the hat?

[image: .]

Comment: what makes you think you earned it *here*?

Comment: @Shog9 Then what's the hat I'm wearing???

Comment: You can earn hats anywhere & wear 'em anywhere else... https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Db8I.png

Comment: @Shog9 I added a screenshot.

Comment: Look toward the bottom-left of your screenshot where it lists the sites you've earned the hat on...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see a partial list of sites where you've earned the hat in your hat rack.  Your screen shot does not show this site there, though in theory it could be hidden behind "10 other sites".  You can see the complete list by opening the hat on the [Winterbash site](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/).  Click on the hat to see a display like this:

[image: screen shot]

If you do that and find this site in the list please update with a screenshot.  I predict that you won't find this site on the list.

You can wear hats that you've earned anywhere on the network; just because you're wearing it here doesn't mean you earned it here.